# Creating android projects based on another source

Tags: java, android, project

I am making a barcode scanner app, but when i am creating a new project with some files as source, i dont understand how. Before i updated eclipse, adt and the Android sdk, i had an option for that when i was creating a new project. But now i cant see it. How can i do so? I have eclipse version 3.7.0 and android sdk manager revision 20.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a new project (from source), use import and choose the source project

Comment: That only works if the source project has Eclipse project files.

Comment: File -> Import -> Android Project From Existing Code, worked perfectly fine without any Eclipse generated project files

Comment: Oh, sorry -- I didn't notice they added an Android option in there. My apologies!

Answer (score 0):

**1.** I think you mean **library project** by source file.

**2.**

```
R_Click on your project directory in Package Explorer ---> Select Properties

   ---> Select Android ---> Scroll Down till end, and You will see the Option

   ---> Select the library project.
```

**3.** But before this, do the same as above for the Project that needs to be made as library and tick the **"Library"** check box.

Answer (score 0):

Use File > New > Project > Android Project From Existing Code -- they pulled this capability out from the standard new-Android-project wizard.